# How can I preproduce a plot like below?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Can I as how to reproduce a plot indicated below using the following code in ggplot2 or any other ploting method?
How can I show the data points/samples to reflect **group variable** and the expression level of the gene
**"OXC"**?
Thank you!

```
 dad <- data.frame(OYC = rnorm(50),
                   OXC = rnorm(50),
                   FG  = runif(50, min = 60, max = 300),
                   GTT = runif(50, min= 0, max = 20),
                   group = rep(c("Aaa", "Bbb", "Ccc", "Ddd"), time = c(15, 12, 8,15)))
 row.names(dad) <- paste("sample_", 1:50)
 
 library(ggplot2)
 dad %>%
   ggplot(aes(x=FG, y= GTT, Color = OXC)) + 
   geom_point() + 
   theme(axis.title=element_text(size = 12,face="bold", colour = "blue"),
         axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
         title=element_text(size= 12,face="bold"))+
   labs(y= "ggt", x = "FG")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this? I have used the data you shared. The key is to use the `shape` aesthetic element in your `aes()`. It will create shapes instead of common points. After that if you want additional customization, you can use `scale_shape_manual()` in order to define different shapes. Here somo options for you. The numeric color scale can be also added with `color` or `fill` aesthetic elements. Here the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#Plot
dad %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=FG, y= GTT, color = OXC, shape=factor(group))) + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme(axis.title=element_text(size = 12,face="bold", colour = "blue"),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
        title=element_text(size= 12,face="bold"))+
  labs(y= "ggt", x = "FG")
```

Output:

[image]

And if you want to set different colors you can use this:

```
#Plot 2
dad %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=FG, y= GTT, color = OXC, shape=factor(group))) + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme(axis.title=element_text(size = 12,face="bold", colour = "blue"),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
        title=element_text(size= 12,face="bold"))+
  labs(y= "ggt", x = "FG")+
  scale_color_gradient2(low = 'red',mid = 'green',high = 'yellow')
```

Output:

[image]

And a few level of customization:

```
#Plot 3
dad %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=FG, y= GTT, color = OXC, shape=factor(group))) + 
  geom_point(size=3) + 
  theme(axis.title=element_text(size = 12,face="bold", colour = "blue"),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
        title=element_text(size= 12,face="bold"))+
  labs(y= "ggt", x = "FG")+
  scale_shape_manual(values = c('circle','square','triangle','diamond'))+
  scale_color_gradient2(low = 'red',mid = 'yellow',high = 'blue')
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plot that gets you close to what your example looks like (black lines around the shapes, diverging blue/red scale). You were not getting color in your original code because the color aesthetic is `color` and not `Color`. Using `scale_shape_manual`, you can select shapes that have a solid outline and a fill. Then you assign your color variable to `fill`to fill those shapes. Using `scale_fill_gradient2`, you can define a divergent scale

```
dad %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=FG, y= GTT, fill = OXC, shape = group)) + 
  geom_point(size = 5) + 
  theme(axis.title=element_text(size = 12,face="bold", colour = "blue"),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
        title=element_text(size= 12,face="bold"))+
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("Aaa" = 21, "Bbb" = 22, "Ccc" = 23, "Ddd" = 24)) + 
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "red", mid = "white", high = "blue") + 
  labs(y= "ggt", x = "FG")
```

[image]